# Update bigdata table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-update, sql-server-2014, bigdata

I need help to update my one table column from another table, here is my situation.

- Hardware: 8GB Ram, Xeon Processor, 1 TB Internal Harddisk
- Software: SQL Server 2014

I have two SQL Server database and each has a table.

1. `table1` (`db1`) 275MN+ row count, 350 columns, unique column = `Id` (18 char in each Id), to be updated columns = `U_col1`, `U_col2`
2. `table2` (`db2`) 230MN+ row count, 8 columns, unique column = `Id` (18 char in each Id), to be set columns = `_col1`, `_col2`

Here is my query for update:

```
Update db1.table1
set T1.U_col1 = T2._col1, T1.U_col2 = T2._col2
from db1.table1 T1, db2.table2 T2
where T1.Id = T2.Id
```

I had not added any indexes because of the performance issues.

So suggest how to run successfully all columns to be updated.

Give me some answers of this questions.

1. Can I run update without using any indexes?
2. Suggest which index to be use on which column(s) in both tables (clustered, non-clustered, clustered column store)
3. Or any other index or update trick

I am Ok if query runs 24 hours, 36 hours or may be more but I want to complete the query successfully.

Let me know if you want to know anything else?

Comment: Just to clarify, your update already works reliably and you just want help with speeding it up? Or is this about spotting subtle mistakes in the query?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hey, @Yunnosch, I wanted to speed up query performance, query is all right, it's my update query looks alike.I wanted to know is their i can add index before execute update query and if yes which type of index i can create? or if no, then can i run update without indexing ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run update without using any indexes?

Yes, but performance may be prohibitive updating 200M+ rows in a single statement with only 8GB RAM, single spinning disk, and no supporting indexes.

More importantly, you might also run into log space issues updating so many rows in a single batch. To be safe, it would be best to make sure the database recovery model is `SIMPLE` and perform updates in batches to mitigate log space requirements.

> Suggest which index to be use on which column(s) in both tables
>   (clustered, non-clustered, clustered column store)

Unique clustered index on the ID column of each table.

> Or any other index or update trick

Specify a TABLOCKX hint.

Here's the `UPDATE` with the hints using ANSI-92 join syntax.

```
UPDATE T1
SET
      T1.U_col1 = T2._col1
    , T1.U_col2 = T2._col2
FROM dbo.table1 AS T1 WITH(TABLOCKX)
JOIN dbo.table2 AS T2 WITH(TABLOCKX) ON T1.Id = T2.Id;
```

Add a `WHERE` clause to update in smaller batches by the clustered index key in a loop. I don't know the format of the char(18) ID data so I can't be more specific about how to determine the key ranges.  The goal is to update no more than a few GB of data per batch. Updates are faster when all data updated in a single transaction fit in memory.

```
UPDATE T1
SET
      T1.U_col1 = T2._col1
    , T1.U_col2 = T2._col2
FROM dbo.table1 AS T1 WITH(TABLOCKX)
JOIN dbo.table2 AS T2 WITH(TABLOCKX) ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE T1.Id BETWEEN @StartKey AND @EndKey;
```